# How can I connect to a 2FA VPN on Linux?

Tags: vpn, citrix, netscaler, anyconnect, openconnect

I need to connect to the office VPN from a linux machine. I'm able to connect to it only via Citrix NetScaler Gateway on Windows. The connection needs the secondary password (in my case is an OTP from Mobile Pass App) and I have all the client and ca certificates needed.

I've tried Cisco AnyConnect but I always get the following error message:

> AnyConnect cannot confirm it is connected to your secure gateway. The local network may not be trustworthy. Please try another network.

I've also tried OpenConnect with which I always got:

> XML response has no "auth" node

Other VPN clients like FortiClient does not support secondary password so I can't make them work and I can't find any solution for those errors. Is there a way to make one of them working or obtain a version of Citrix NetScaler Gateway compatible with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a Linux client. Even if maybe not as up to date as Linux or Mac client.

If you unpack the NetScaler firmware you have files like

```
nsgclient32.deb
nsgclient64.deb
nsginstaller[32|64].[deb|rpm]
```

I run the `nsgclient64.deb` package on an Ubuntu 14.04 and it works just fine for my needs.
All you have to do is configure `.citrix/userConfiguration.conf` and then fire it up with `NSGClient -c`.

If you want you can also connect via the browser. But I prefer to have more control over it by using the cli.

Answer (score 0):

NetScaler Gateway full VPN requires a NetScaler Gateway client installed.
There is no Linux version.
Only Windows, Mac, IOS and Android.
You can download them from the Citrix downloads site under NetScaler Gateway > Plugins & Clients and pick the version you want.